# Python: Convert hex notation to binary string

Tags: python, binary, hex

I have a binary format specification. The specification lists tags/objects in hex notation like `0x1000` which in the actual file when read into bytes in python is the binary string `b'\x00\x10'`.

There are 100s of tags and an existing mapping file is available that maps each "hex code" to a specific tag. Hence I want to be able to do a simple look-up to get the correct tag, eg. convert the `0x1000`to `b'\x00\x10'` (one-time precomputed value that I can then simply compare to).

So how can I do this conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referenced link partially answers the question.

```
 0x1000.to_bytes(2, byteorder='little')
```

works and yes the `0x1000` can be written exactly like that without any quotes. Eg. hex literals is the actually trick I wasn't aware of. TIL.